# Comparing Google Map LatLngs

Tags: javascript, google-maps

While trying to compare 2 Google Map LatLngs to see if they were the at the same coordinates, I found that `===` and `==` don't work.

I know the points are the same because I've tested it with the same values and calculated the distance between them which requires the inclusion of the Google Map's Geometry library. I know I can check if the distance between them is 0 units to see if they are the same but I'd rather leave the library out if I could.

My test: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oma5ybwm/1/)

Is is possible to compare them using basic JavaScript? If not, what is the simplest way of comparing 2 Google Map LatLngs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert them in string by using the `toString()` of JS:

```
if (pos1.toString() == pos2.toString()) {
    alert("Equal");
} else {
    alert("Not Equal");
}
```

As pos1 and pos2 has the value like: (-45,108) and to compare it you need to use `toString()` function.

Here is working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gfj8f87L/).